# what is the best solution/architecture for implementing localization in an application written in unmanaged C?

Tags: c++, localization

what is the best solution/architecture for implementing localization in an application written in unmanaged C ?

Should I use [MUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264325%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), something based on [boost::locale](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/boost_locale/html/index.html) or something very classic (I will post this below as first response). Or maybe something else... [setlocale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e22ty2t%28VS.80%29.aspx) seems too simple.

Can I change language at runtime ? I didn't see any application to do so.

PS: If matters I want to target Windows Xp

Regards

Comment: unmanaged C ? Did you mean C++ ?

Comment: technically speaking C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard approach seems to be: One directory for each language that will contain module localizations (dlls containing text and images). Most probably one for each module in application and will contain only resources.
Application will set this module as default (using AfxSetResourceHandle or something equivalent) and will redirect all LoadString calls to this module.
One problem in this approach is that resources will be once in the module and once again (translated) in localization module.